# La pronuncia della parola febbrìle (in opposizione agli errati fèbbrile e fébbrile) è determinabile dalle regole di pronuncia delle lingua italiana?

Tags: pronunciation

Capisco che la parola venga dal latino e possa aver ereditato la pronuncia, ma mi chiedo se tale pronuncia è, ad oggi, perfettamente spiegabile sulla sola base delle regole.

Comment: Quali regole di pronuncia della lingua italiana? L'accento in italiano è libero, cioè non sottostà a nessuna regola...

Comment: Quando parli di “regole” a quali ti riferisci, esattamente?

Comment: Be', forse non sono regole ma solo convenzioni consolidate? Forse sto pensando solo a quello che voglio pensare e chiedo scusa se è così, ma non tutte le parole che terminano per -zione hanno l'accento sulla o? A cercare proprio ora, ho trovato [questo su Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento-fonico-prontuario_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/). Non è forse questa, la regola? C'è l'esempio di "canile" che è piana. Allora anche "febbrile" è piana per lo stesso motivo (cioè derivate/alterate uscenti in -ile), no?

Comment: Non le chiamerei nemmeno convenzioni: le lingue naturali prendono un po' la strada che vogliono. La Treccani infatti non si sbilancia a parlare di “regole” o simili, ma dice solo che possiamo “prevedere” l'accento di certe classi di parole. A parte che al capoverso dopo ci sono le eccezioni date dalle parole in -abile e -ibile, anche senza mi vengono in mente al volo almeno “utènsile” e “fìssile”. Insomma, in italiano, quando si ha un dubbio (e, come dice anche quella pagina, la pronuncia “pone spesso problemi anche a persone con un buon livello di istruzione”) tocca consultare un dizionario.

Comment: Comunque hai fatto bene a trovare quella pagina: più di quello che dicono lì non credo proprio che si possa fare, a parte appunto elencare tutte le singole parole come in un dizionario.

Comment: @DaG, grazie. A volte mi affretto a scrivere una domanda e solo dopo spendo più energie a pensarci! :') Col senno di poi, forse vale la pena che io cancelli la domanda.

Comment: @Enlico non penso tu debba cancellare la domanda. Il fatto che non ci siano hard rules riguardo agli accenti è già una risposta che può essere utile a chi non ne fosse a conoscenza.